# Computing Simple Slopes for 3-Way Interaction in Multilevel Model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, simple-effects

[image]I have several significant 3-way interactions in a 2-level models (individuals nested in couples), and I am struggling with the computation of the simple slopes. Essentially, my categorical level-2 variable (couple is classified as distressed/violent or distress/non-violent) moderates the level-1 cross product of gender and satisfaction to predict conflict behavior. I am using HLM software, and I've always used Preacher's website to compute my simple slopes, but he doesn't have any options for this combination of level-2 and level-1 interactions.

I'm not finding a ton of information online. It seems like some (most?) people just run two sets of analyses for each of the groups, but that seems to be an inelegant solution at the very least.

**Edit to clarify:** See my model, and then my output. I have data from ~85 couples (170 individuals) who completed several questionnaires during a single lab visit.

The **level-1** variables ending in "**_S**" are cross-products (computed in SPSS) between "PARTNER" (female or male) and the three continuous level-1 predictors (i.e., FLOOD, DAS, PCLEAD). "COU_TYPE" (violent or non-violent) is a between-level (level-2) predictor.

In several instances, "COU_TYPE" is a significant moderator of those level-1  cross-products (circled in red).

Is there a way to compute the simple slopes/effects for men in the violent group, men in the non-violent group, women in the violent group, and women in the non-violent group?

Comment: What is a "simple slope" and what does Preacher's website say ? Rather than giving a link to an external source please provide all the information necessary. Also please provide full details of your model as well as the output.

Comment: Hi - I clarified my question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks. But please don't post pitures of ooutput. You can post the output itself and just enclose the whole block with three backticks at the top and bottom and it will display nicely.